# How to view folder path in finder? How to find multiple windows of an application?

Tags: macos, shortcuts, window, finder, gui

I am having a lot of questions with mac OS.

How do I view / copy the path of a folder in finder?

How to bring a window to the front? 
How to cycle through multiple windows of an app, say, Intellij?

Comment: I see about five different questions here. Ask one thing at a time.

Comment: Read https://support.apple.com/HT204216

Answer (score 1):

For seeing/copying path, right-click(two finger single tap) on the folder and hold alt. Copy Folder will change to copy folder as pathname.

Three finger swipe up and you'll be in Mission Control and click on the window you want up. Alternatively, press alt-tab.

If same app has multiple windows, press <kbd>command</kbd>+ <kbd>`</kbd> (the one with `~`)(the one beside `1`). Alternatively, use Window menu.

You are very welcome to browse Ask Different (https://apple.stackexchange.com) and this site itself with [macos](/questions/tagged/macos) etc to learn usage or shortcuts. Changing a laptop because you couldn't learn shortcuts in a few days as compared to the years old windows seems petty.

You can also go to any app in Help menu and learn about it. In Finder,  it is macOS help, or Safari, it is Safari help. I am pretty sure you skipped such help pages.